# Python *args **kwargs

Tags: python

Code:

```
def my_fun(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("request = ", request)
    print("args = ", args)
    print("kwargs = ", kwargs)

fun_args = ("analytic", tuple(), {'run':True, 'override':10})

my_fun(*fun_args)
```

My existing definition my_fun() is like mentioned above and call my_fun() with fun_args as shown above and I would like to have output as follows:

Expected output:

```
request = analytic
args = ()
kwargs = {'run':True, 'override':10}
```

Can anyone suggest what changes needs to be made while calling my_fun(*fun_args) to get expected output?

I’m not allowed to change definition my_fun() due to some restrictions.

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual output, and explained exactly how that is different from what you wanted.

Comment: On the contrary, this sounds like a perfectly reasonable generic callback scheme.  Parameter 1 is designed for *args, and parameter 2 is designed for **kwargs.

Comment: Never mind me; my reading comprehension appears be non-existent at the moment.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the value of `fun_args`? `fun_args = (("analytic",), {'run': True, 'override': 10})` would make more sense. In general, `fun_args` is a two-tuple containing the positional arguments (and since `request` is required, ia non-empty tuple) and the keyword arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments and time in looking into this, I was trying to see if there is anything to pack variable, tuple, dict into fun_args and call my_fun(*fun_args) to assign tuple, dict to args, kwargs respectively, but i think i'll have to do some workarounds and tweaks to existing def

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can do:

```py
my_fun(fun_args[0], *fun_args[1], **fun_args[2])
```

Prints:

```
request =  analytic
args =  ()
kwargs =  {'run': True, 'override': 10}
```

Comment: @chepner : interesting is in this context that `my_fun("analytic", **{'run':True, 'override':10})` and `my_fun("analytics", *tuple(), *tuple(tuple(tuple())), *tuple(), **{'run':True, 'override':10})` give the same output - this is what you probably tried to say ... but failed to be exact and therefore removed your comment ...

Comment: May you elaborate at least a bit about what is going there under the hood? How does it come that both calls in my previous comment give the same result?